# Conditionally insert date separator to array of chat messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Chat feature, similar to Slack, where the messages are grouped by date. I'm using the groupdate gem to put all of the messages together in a hash, and then print them out in the browser where messages are grouped by the date they were sent on:

```
@messages = @chatroom.messages.group_by_day { |message| message.created_at }

- @messages.each do |day, messages|
  %li.date_divider
  = "#{day.strftime("%B %d")}"
    %ul
      - messages.each do |message|
        %li= message.content
```

For performance, it's crazy to load months worth of messages all at once and I'm trying to think how I can approach this by paginating the messages and using some sort of infinite autoscroll. I can get this working fine using `@pagy, @messages = pagy(@chatroom.messages)` but all of it goes to hell when I use the `group_by_day` and returned in a hash. I was curious if you anyone could shed some input on how to approach this where I can still benefit from the user-experience by grouping messages by date, but also benefit from the performance in the case outlined above.

Alternative to using `group_by_day`, one suggestion is to paginate an array of messages ordered by date and conditionally add the extra date display in the loop to display when the next item have a new date compared to the previous one, but I'm unsure how to do this off the top of my head.

Comment: as I remember both `kaminari` and `will_paginate` supports paginating an array

Comment: Pagy supports arrays as well. My question is how to conditionally add the extra date display in the loop to act as a separator. When you login to Slack channel, the messages are grouped by the date they were sent on.

Answer (score 3):

You're not far of an actual working version, when you do:

```rb
# controller
@pagy, @messages = pagy(@chatroom.messages)
```

The messages are stored in `@messages`. When you call `@chatroom.messages.group_by_day` you call `group_by_day` upon all messages belonging to the chatroom. Instead use `@messages.group_by_day` which holds the messages that are retuned by pagy.

```haml
-# view
- @messages = @messages.group_by_day { |message| message.created_at }

- @messages.each do |day, messages|
  -# ...
```

---

For infinite scroll there you might want to use a library. The basic idea is to fetch messages from the server when the user scrolls close to the top or bottom of the page. You then insert them in the correct place in the HTML using JavaScript.

Note that you don't have to do one or the other. You could have an infinite scroll that groups the messages by date. Although it might be somewhat harder to implement.

I'm leaving the details out of this answer since that deserves it's own question. Note that you shouldn't create a new question instantly. First have a [look around the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScript+infinite+scroll) for different libraries or methods to create your own, try to work something out. Then if you get stuck or have a specific question you should create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to save the last date in a variable at the end of the outer loop (so after your messages have been printed. Once the condition `day != previous_day` is met, you print the divisor

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom search to pagy in order to display the items in the way you want to be displayed. For example do something like:

```
@pagy, @messages = pagy(Chatroom.customSearch(params[:q]), items: 20)
```

In your `Chatroom` model you can create the `customSearch` function. Find all chatRoom messages you want, order and send them back to pagy. Hope it helps.